# Converting IPv6 to integer in BigQuery standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ipv6

I tired converting IP address to integer. It worked for IPv4 but while doing IPv6 i got error saying

> NET.IPV4_TO_INT64() encountered a non-IPv4 address. Expected 4 bytes but got 16

How to convert IP address both IPv4 & IPv6?

Comment: An IPv6 address is 128 bits long, and all of the bits are relevant. You cannot expect to fit one into a 32 bit integer, and I don't think BigQuery has a 128-bit integer type.

Comment: Hi Damien_The_Unbeliever, Please let me know if there is any way that i could actually convert IPv6 to integer ?

Comment: You would need to have 128-bit integers. IPv4 addresses are 32-bit unsigned integers, regardless of the dotted-decimal notation, which is just to make it easier for humans to read, but an actual IPv4 address (the way network devices see and use it) is a 32-bit unsigned integer. An IPv6 address is a 128-bit unsigned integer, and that is how network devices see and use it. You simply cannot fit a 128-bit data structure into a 32-bit data structure.

Comment: @Sunil if the workaround helped somehow, consider accepting/upvoting

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert a **IPV6** to a decimal value, you can use a `JavaScript` UDF just like below. Please have in mind that the numeric value resulting from this operation needs to be represented as a STRING because its too big to fit into a `BigQuery` number type

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ipv6_to_number(ip STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
var parts = [];
    ip.split(":").forEach(function(it) {
        var bin = parseInt(it, 16).toString(2);
        while (bin.length < 16) {
            bin = "0" + bin;
        }
        parts.push(bin);
    })
    var bin = parts.join("");
    var dec = BigInt("0b"+ bin)
    return dec;

""";

Select "2001:0db8:0:0:8d3:0:0:0" ip, ipv6_to_number("2001:0db8:0:0:8d3:0:0:0") number
```

Result:

```
Row ip                         number   
1   2001:0db8:0:0:8d3:0:0:0    42540766411282592857539836924043198464
```