# BigQuery Convert IPV4 and IPV6 into a number to allow a match between start and end IP address ranges?

Tags: google-bigquery, ipv6

I'm building a BigQuery based data schema that will check whether a source IP address is within a declared IP address start/end range.  To handle this, I will converting the source IP address and start/end range values into numbers.

I can see BigQuery NET functions for converting an IPV4 to a number, but I can't find the equivalent for IPV6

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same problem. So now I declare ip ranges using `NET.IP_TRUNC`.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/net_functions#netip_trunc

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of BigQuery there is no equivalent of the **NET** function to convert an IPV6 address to a number. However in BigQuery you can write JavaScript [user-defined functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) in legacy SQL query syntax for your requirement.

You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753232/converting-ipv6-to-integer-in-bigquery-standard-sql) for UDF using Javascript. I tried the code and it is converting an IPV6 address to a number.

**Code :**

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ipv6_to_number(ip STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
var parts = [];
   ip.split(":").forEach(function(it) {
       var bin = parseInt(it, 16).toString(2);
       while (bin.length < 16) {
           bin = "0" + bin;
       }
       parts.push(bin);
   })
   var bin = parts.join("");
   var dec = BigInt("0b"+ bin)
   return dec;

""";
Select "2020:0db9:0:0:8e3:0:0:0" ip, ipv6_to_number("2020:0db9:0:0:8e3:0:0:0") number
```

**Output:**

[image]

As per your requirement, you want a return type of Integer. I created a logic where the datatype is returned as BigInt.

**code :**

```
ip="2020:0db9:0:0:8e3:0:0:0";
const parts=[];
const arr=ip.split(":");
const data=arr.forEach(function(it){
   var bin=parseInt(it,16).toString(2);
   while(bin.length<16){
       bin="0"+bin;
       var bin1=parseInt(bin);

   }
   parts.push(bin1);
   });

var bin1=parts.join("");
var dec=BigInt("0b"+bin1);
console.log(dec);
console.log(typeof dec);
```

**output:**

```
4415686854424n
bigint
```

When you will use this function in UDF, Bigquery will throw an error :

[image]

This is because IPv6 uses a 128-bit address, which is **16 bytes**. There is no numeric [data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#supported-javascript-udf-data-types) in BigQuery which is large enough to hold a numeric form of IPv6 address.  BigQuery supports **INT64** data type which is **8 bytes**.

You will need to consider using BYTES to hold the IPv6 address or you can use the return type as String in your UDF.

**For a compressed IPv6 address:**

For a compressed IPv6 address like **“2001:0db8::0001” , “2001:4ca0:6fff::”**  you can refer to  the below steps:

**Step 1: pre-process the IPv6  address (expand the address from a compressed one)**

You can refer to the below code :

**ipdeocde.js**

```
ipval="2001:4ca0:6fff::";
var ip = require('ipaddr.js');
var addr = ip.parse(ipval);
addr.toString();
var ipadd =addr.toNormalizedString();
console.log(ipadd);
console.log(typeof ipadd);
```

**output:**

```
2001:4ca0:6fff:0:0:0:0:0
String
```

**Step 2: Running the UDF**

After expanding the Ipv6 address you can use the above UDF in BigQuery to convert the IPv6 address to a number.

If the address is already in expanded format you can directly use the UDF in BigQuery and if the address is in compressed format first you need to process it to convert the address to the expanded format and then run the UDF in BigQuery on the expanded IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I notice that your function returns a string.   I was hoping to get a number value to simplify the process of checking whether an IP address is within a start/end range.

Comment: Hi @user2868835 I have updated the answer.

Comment: This UDF doesn't seem to work for compressed IPv6 e.g. '2001:4ca0:6fff::'

Comment: Thank you @SandeepMohanty
can 'require' be used inside bigQuery?

Comment: Hi @balafi since **require()** is a javascript function which is used to load various modules, this function cannot be used by BigQuery while writing your UDF from the BigQuery Console. You will get an error like **"ReferenceError: require is not defined"**. For that reason you need to preprocess the IPv6 address first using the **“ipdecode.js”** code. However if you want to use require(), you can write your own custom code using the [Bigquery Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) Client library to make the process work.

Comment: If it helped you to solve your problem, please consider to accept and upvote it as per [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).